# How to query using column names that include "$"?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark SQL, I can use

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "warehouseLocation-value")
      .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.json("source/myRecords.json")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("shipment")
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM shipment")
```

to get the data from "myRecords.json", and the structure of this json file is:

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- container: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- barcode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
```

I can get the specific column of this json such as:

```
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT container.barcode, container.code FROM shipment")
```

But how can I get id.$oid from this json file?
I have tried `"SELECT id.$oid FROM shipment_log"` or `"SELECT id.\$oid FROM shipment_log"`, but not work at all.
error message:

```
 error: invalid escape character
```

Can any one tell me how can I get `id.$oid` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backticks are your friend:

```
spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq(
  """{"_id": {"$oid": "foo"}}""")
)).createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql("SELECT _id.`$oid` FROM df").show
```

```
+----+
|$oid|
+----+
| foo|
+----+
```

Same as `DataFrame` API:

```
spark.table("df").select($"_id".getItem("$oid")).show
```

```
+--------+
|_id.$oid|
+--------+
|     foo|
+--------+
```

or

```
spark.table("df").select($"_id.$$oid")
```

```
+--------+
|_id.$oid|
+--------+
|     foo|
+--------+
```